# Dynamic updating of label/button title in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I want to update the `title` property of a user interface element on iOS using Swift. In this case it is a UIBarButton, but it could be a UILabel, UIButton or whatever. Currently I am using this code, which works:

```
func setStatusMessage(barButton: UIBarButtonItem) {
    let currentVersion = StatusModel.getCurrentVersion()
    var statusUpdates = [StatusModel]()
    var statusForCurrentVersion: StatusModel!
    var statusMessage = String()

    // check if update required before setting the text
    checkIfLocalStatusNeedsUpdate()
    barButton.title = getLocalStatusMessage()

    // Try to update status anyway...
    getStatusFromRemoteSource { (statusUpdates) -> Void in

        for status in statusUpdates {
            if status.version == currentVersion {
                statusForCurrentVersion = status
            }
        }

        self.saveStatusFromRemoteSource(statusForCurrentVersion)
        barButton.title = statusForCurrentVersion.message
    }

}
```

Although effective, this solution is ugly too as it does require a user interface (view) element to be embedded in my model. Not exactly a sort of MVC beauty.....

I cannot simply use `return` because the local status will be returned before the remote status can be fetched. So I guess I need some kind of handler / listener / delegate (`/*getting lost here*/`) to update the view dynamically. In this case that means: set the title using the locally stored value and update it if a remote value is received.

What is the best way to approach this scenario in a MVC compliant way, removing UI elements from the model code (thereby increasing reusability)?

Answer (score 0):

One intermediate step you could do is going over the controller to the UI, by replacing the barButton parameter with a reference to the controller

```
barButton.title = statusForCurrentVersion.message
->
self.controller.update(title: statusForCurrentVersion.message)
```

This way your code is allowed to grow (updating more labels etc), but it comes with a cost of more code and harder readability.

Comment: I did a few experiments, but unsuccessfully. What is this `controller` instance? XCode gives me the error that it does not know `controller`, which makes sense to me, but making it an instance of the current UIViewController does not help either...